# combine two awk commands NF and BEGIN (.csv processing)

Tags: awk, command-line

How to combine two awk commands:

1. `awk NF file_name.csv > file_name_after_NF.csv` the output is used in next step:
2. `awk 'BEGIN{f=""}{if($0!=f){print $0}if(NR==1){f=$0}}' file_name_after_NF.csv > file_name_postprocess.csv`

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of input data (ie, rows from `file_name.csv`) and the expected output (ie, corresponding rows from 'file_name_postprocess.csv`)

Comment: please update the question with your attempt(s) to combine the code and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: Neither of these scripts seem suitable for meaningfully processing CSV files (comma-separated values).

Comment: Putting on my mind-reader hat, it looks like you're trying to remove blank lines and any duplicated header lines from your csv. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the intermediate file `file_name_after_NF.csv` was written soley to feed the 'no blank lines' version of the `.csv` file into the 'remove repeat lines' command, the two procedures can be combined by making `NF` the *condition pattern* for the main awk code block:

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=""} NF{if($0!=f){print $0}if(NR==1){f=$0}}' file_name.csv > file_name_postprocess.csv
```

In the above procedure, the main awk block is only applied where there are one or more fields in the record.

If you need a file copy of `file_name_after_NF.csv`, this can be created by adding a file-write block within the main block of the previous awk procedure:

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=""} NF{if($0!=f){print $0}if(NR==1){f=$0}{print $0 > file_name_after_NF.csv}}' file_name.csv > file_name_postprocess.csv
```

`{print $0 > file_name_after_NF.csv}` does the file writing from within awk. As this block is within the main block processed according to the NF condition pattern, only lines with fields are written to `file_name_after_NF.csv`

More generally, if a little more cumbersomely, awk procedures can be combined by piping their output into successive awk procedures. In your case this could be achieved using:

```
awk NF file_name.csv | awk 'BEGIN{f=""}{if($0!=f){print $0}if(NR==1){f=$0}}' > file_name_postprocess.csv
```

or, if you need the intermediate file, again include an awk file print block:

```
awk NF file_name.csv | awk 'BEGIN{f=""}{if($0!=f){print $0}if(NR==1){f=$0}{print $0 > file_name_after_NF.csv}}' > file_name_postprocess.csv
```

**Edit** dealing with cases where the header line is after one or more blank lines

@glennjackman raised a point relating to an example where blank lines existed before the first/header row, since the `NR==1` condition in the first two examples above would no longer reset `f` to contain the header. The last two examples, where awk procedures are joined by pipes, would still work but the first two would not.

To fix this, a further variable can be added to the `BEGIN` awk block that is updated as soon as the first non-empty line is seen in the main block. This allows for that line to be identified so that prior empty lines do not matter:

```
awk 'BEGIN{f="";headerFlag="none"} NF{if($0!=f){print $0}if(headerFlag=="none"){f=$0;headerFlag="yes"}}' file_name.csv > file_name_postprocess.csv
```

The conditional `NR==1` in the original script is changed here to check whether the the `headerFlag` set in `BEGIN` has been changed. If not, `f` is set to track repeats of the line and `headerFlag` is changed so the block will only run on the first encounter of a non-empty record.

The same change can be used in the second solution above.

Comment: What happens if the initial file *starts with* blank lines? The `NR == 1` test isn't quite right in that case.

Comment: @glennjackman good point. The latter general solutions will still work, will have a think about the first ones.

Comment: @glennjackman  flag added to `BEGIN` to use as header conditional instead of `NR==1` for cases where the header follows empty lines and for which `NR>1`

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't planning to try to answer this until after you posted sample input and expected output but since you already have answers, here's my guess at what you might be asking how to write:

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=""} !NF{next} $0!=f; f==""{f=$0}' file_name.csv > file_name_postprocess.csv
```

but without sample input/output it's untested.

I'd recommend you start using white space in your code to improve readability btw.

Also - testing `NF` for a CSV without setting FS to `,` is probably the wrong thing to do but idk if you're trying to skip lines of all blanks or lines of all commas or something else so idk what the right thing is to do but maybe it's this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; f=""} $0~("^"FS"*$"){next} $0!=f; f==""{f=$0}' file_name.csv > file_name_postprocess.csv
```